# To deal with superfluous carriage returns in TextEdit

Tags: ms-office, text-editor, textedit, formatting

I want to let TextEdit never save `<CR>`, the carriage return.

Different operating systems save end-of-line as different Unicode characters. 
For MS DOS (like Windows) it is `<CR><LF>`, and for Unix and Mac `<LF>`, and for the very old Mac OS 9 just `<CR>`. 
Here `<CR>` is the carriage return, and `<LF>` the line feed.

When sometimes I paste, into TextEdit, several paragraphs from a Windows-created file, for example `pdf` or `doc`/`docx`, `<CR>`'s are also copied. 
TextEdit does not fully conform with Unix standards, in that it does accept `<CR><LF>`'s, by showing them indeed as line breaks. 
I cannot tell, then, whether a line break is Window-styled `<CR><LF>` or Unix-styled `<LF>`.

When I save my personal writings in pure text (`txt`) written in Markdown, I don't want these `<CR>`'s, but can neither see them, nor delete them in TextEdit. 
It is when I open the text file in question with Vim, did I spot those `<CR>`'s shown as `^M`. 
Indeed, in Vim, it is easy to replace them with empty strings.

However, I too edit in TextEdit often. 
Can I set TextEdit so that it never saves `<CR>`'s in a buffer of its? 
That is, when I paste a `<CR>` in a buffer, the `<CR>` is ignored and not written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that TextEdit has such an option.  It happily accepts all line ending types (even intermixed within the same file) and displays them properly.

You would probably need to use a text editor where you have direct control over the line endings and text encoding type when saving the file.  [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/) is a great text editor that has such controls.

Another option is to convert the file with a utility like [dos2unix](http://waterlan.home.xs4all.nl/dos2unix.html).  The website doesn't offer a macOS binary download so you would need to either compile it yourself or install a package manager like [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) first then install the dos2unix package with `brew install dos2unix`. For an easy solution you can just run `perl -pi -e 's/\r\n/\n/;' FILE.TXT` as well.

Comment: I would suggest a better solutino than `dos2unix` since it would fix occurences everywhere: `perl -pi -e 's/\r//g ;' file.txt`.

Comment: Sorry I forgot this question completely. Actually, I don't mind open Vim and batch-replace by `:bufdo %s/\r/\r/g`. Your suggestions are all reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

When I understand you right, the problem lies in the OSX Clipboard. It's the place to fix the behaviour, if there is one. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482289/easiest-way-to-strip-newline-character-from-input-string-in-pasteboard on how to deal with newlines in the OSX Clipboard.